# Phonegap create command automation

Tags: java, php, android, cordova

For a website I need to take user input for folder name and execute "create" command for android project from phonegap.  How do i do this using php command shell_exec()? Does php require special:
java
android 
ant 
permissions. What are the changes to be made?

Comment: Have you got solution for this? can you share???